# NuGet ID Verified Mark in MyGet feeds

Tags: nuget, myget

Since NuGet implemented [NuGet Package ID Prefix reservation](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/wiki/NuGet-Package-Identity-Verification#nuget-package-id-prefix-reservation), latest versions of Visual Studio show a new icon for verified packages.

Today I've noticed all packages in my custom MyGet feed got the same icon, however, I did not make any additional change.

Is this the expected behavior in MyGet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the [NuGet protocol does not really describe when a package should be "verified"](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/wiki/NuGet-Package-Identity-Verification#nuget-package-id-prefix-reservation) when used outside of Nuget.org, we at MyGet now use the following convention:

- If a package originates from a MyGet feed, it is shown as "verified" (e.g. it comes from your feed)
- If a package is proxied from, e.g. NuGet.org, the package is never shown a verified as MyGet reaches out upstream to fetch the package and its not part of your feed yet. Additionally, since the V2 protocol does not expose the verified boolean, we can never show the verified label for upstream package sources.